# Areas in MEAN stack

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

I have a portal say "www.xxxx.com" and we have to create a sub portal for a particular company say "www.xxxx.com/company1" where in we put all controllers and views based on an Area "Company1". Is there any similar way to do this in the MEAN stack? In ASP.NET MVC we can achieve a similar thing using Areas

Comment: Hope I didn't misunderstand you, but as long as you reference the controllers and views correctly in your app file, it doesn't matter how you structure your controllers and views. Here's some inspiration as to how to structure your controllers/views for each page. https://github.com/sahat/hackathon-starter

Comment: Thanks. We have created a similar structure for this, was wondering if this was the right way to proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. If you are using express, then just define your sub portal in views folder like "views/company1.html" (or if you are using another template engine like jade or ejs, use "views/comapny1.jade || views/comapny.ejs") & then use this code in your directory app.js :

Also, set the default engine you are using by:

```
 app.set('view engine', 'jade');
            Or
 app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

 app.get('/company1').function(req, res) {
     res.render('comapny1.html');
 }
```

Then you can able to access your subportal by using www.xxxx.com/company1. 
Basically, company1.html will be a layout / base file for your sub portal, where you can define your controllers, services, directive etc.

If still, you have any problem in doing this, you can post your response.

Comment: Thanks, we have created a folder structure and using a similar express route logic. Wanted to know if this was the right way to proceed

Comment: ya, its right way, as i have also created a marketplace app using same approach, where buyer and seller have different portals. in my case, i have something like : www.xxxx.com/seller (seller),  www.xxxx.com/admin (admin) & www.xxxx.com (Buyer).  All have their separate depencies.

Comment: Could we also have a middle ware that decides which route to follow in express. For example if both the applications have a similar naming controller for example app.get('/landingpage', homeController.landingpage);. Instead of writing two controllers one for /company1/landingpage and another /landingpage

Comment: To achieve this, you don't need to use a middleware, Beside this, take some prefix in route to separate this.  Like                                    route.get ('/comapny1_getUser', controlObj1.getUsers); route.get ('/comapny2_getUser', controlObj2.getUsers);  where controlObj1 & controlObj2 are the objects returned by controller. if still, you have some confusion, let me know.